# Setting up multiple database with Flyway

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I am trying to setup two different database with Flyway 5.0.7, MySQL for development and H2 for testing. I have configured both databases in respective files.

For **Development**, *src/main/resource/application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/moment
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

flyway.locations=db/migration,db/specific/mysql
```

For **Testing**, *src/test/resource/application.properties*

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

flyway.locations=db/migration,db/specific/h2
```

Below is the folder structure for Flyway migration files

[image: Flyway migration file structure]

In this case Flyway is not able to find migration files under `specific` folder and throws error when applying `V1.1__Insert_Records.sql` for `table not found`.

If I move the `specific` folder inside `db/migration`, I am getting error for duplicate files of same version.

Any suggestions how should I configure migration files for multiple databases to work with Flyway?

Comment: Are you using spring boot 2.x? If so, does the answer below help? If not, what version are you using?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect you might be using Spring Boot 2.x here? If so, `flyway.locations` is no longer valid and will be ignored.

Flyway will then just use the default location (`db/migration`), which will find only the `V1.1__Insert_Records.sql` script but not the `V1__Create_table.sql` script.

With Spring Boot 2.x, [`flyway.locations` must be prefixed with `spring.`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#flyway):

```
spring.flyway.locations=db/migration,db/specific/h2
```

By the way, if you use the `{vendor}` placeholder in the location, [Spring Boot will work out the directory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup) from the lowercase of the database driver id (h2, mysql, oracle, etc), which is nice:

```
spring.flyway.locations=db/migration,db/specific/{vendor}
```

Comment: I had to be specific about the location by prefixing with `classpath`:
`spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration,classpath:/db/specific/h2`